# USB detection with MCU

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, usb

I have USB on a circuit board that I'm working on and it powers up a part of the circuit. I also have my main MCU, SAMD21G, which is not connected to the USB.

I want the MCU to know when the USB is connected. Should I connect the power of the USB to an MCU pin and check if it's high, using a voltage divider to put the voltage down to 3.3 V? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What is the USB connected to?  A USB uart or similar?  (on your board I mean, not the host end)

Comment: USB is used as a secondary charger to the on board battery when it's connected.

Comment: Then yes, use a divider to drive an ADC pin or a GPIO input.  Make sure the series resistor in the divider is large enough to protect the MCU pin.  Don't forget ESD protection.

Comment: Yes, you can use a divider as suggested by Dean Franks. Remember that the USB bus voltage should be within 4.75V-5.25V range. 3k3-2k or 33k-20k pair works for 3V3 systems.